# How do i perform multitasks in mikrobasic for pic12f1840?

Tags: embedded, microchip, rs232

I am having a problem of doing three simultaneous tasks in mikrobasic for pic12f1840.

Here's what i try to do. I need a led flashing at 1 hz in port RA0 meanwhile getting adc conversion at 10 bits between 0 to 5 volts in port RA1 and at the same time to send those to RS232 to be read through hyperterminal. I have some idea that this can be done with timer interrupts but i dont know how to do that. Mind sharing a code or some guidelines of how to achieve this? RS232 signals can be exchanged between RA3 as input and RA4 as output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for code written to a specification is off-topic. I recommend demonstrating what you've done so far, and discussing the problems encountered!

Comment: I  was not aware that the way how i posted my question would piss off someone, i'm sure in the user guidelines i haven't read the part where it says asking for a code is prohibited or discouraged. Gee this way to approach newcomers is really very rude!.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use cooperative multitasking.  You don't even need to use a timer interrupt for this.  Because you have 3 tasks that run concurrently, one approach is to use state machines in your main loop.

What I do is to set Tmr0 to roll over at some specific interval.  I choose to use about 1ms in most of my projects.

Set up each task in a state machine.  At every point in each task where you are waiting for something to happen, exit that state machine and go do the next.

When you get through all of your tasks, waste time in a loop waiting for the Tmr0 Interrupt Flag to trigger.  Note that you do NOT have the Interrupt Enable bit set - you simply are waiting for Tmr0 to roll over.  Using the Interrupt Flag is the easiest way to do this.

When the TMR0IF goes hi, do all of your housekeeping.  This includes updating your real-time clocks and delay timers, processing A/D conversions, etc.  Also be sure to reset TMR0IF for the next pass.

When you are done with housekeeping, simply jump back to the top of the loop and start executing your state machines again.

I have used this approach on most of my projects, including the very simplest (12-bit core) PICs.  It is robust and easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my question, however because i am still learning these things would you mind being a little bit more explicit in your response? like showing an example how do i use the cooperative multitastking your are referring to?. The part where i am lost is to set Tmr0 and so on. Sorry if i do insist but sharing a code example would help me a lot, it doesn't need to be in mikrobasic, this part i can find it on my own how to translate it into that language. It may sound demanding but i really need more help on this matter.

Comment: Google is your friend.  Simply putting the string " cooperative multitasking PIC" into Google yields many results.  Because I've been a member of the PIClist for so many years, one of the first links I would check out is http://www.piclist.com/techref/microchip/multitasking.htm#cooperative